# Is there a mistake in this question: $\forall a\in A: |\{x\in A:x\le a \}|=|\{ y\in B :y\le a \}|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> Two ordered sets $(A,\le_A), (B,\le_B)$ and there's an isomorphic function $f:A\to B$
>
> Prove $\forall a\in A: |\{x\in A:x\le a  \}|=|\{ y\in B :y\le a \}|$

I think there's a mistake in this question, how can you compare elements of $A$ with elements of $B$ ? with which order do you compare them and what if they're disjoint sets ?

Shouldn't it be $|\{ y\in B :y\le f(a) \}|$ ?

Comment: In addition to the two answers below, the $\le$ signs in each set-description should have subscripts (e.g. $x \le_A a$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should be f(a), and the isomorphism required to compare the cardinality is just f restricted to $\{x\epsilon A:x\leq a\}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right, there should be $f(a)$ instead of $a$.